# Setting scrollTop on Firefox causes a bounce

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

This should demonstrate the issue.  It only happens in FF.  Chrome act as expected.

What I'm trying to do (refer to jsfiddle below) is stop scrolling the blue section when the bottom is level with the bottom of the red section.  On FF there will be a slight delay and then a bounce.

```
function adjustPosition() {
    var padding = $(window).height() - (checkoutBtn().offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() + checkoutBtn().height());
    $(window).scrollTop(menuBox().height() - $(window).height() + menuBox().offset().top + padding);
}

function needsPositioned(wheelDelta) {
    return ((checkoutBtn().offset().top + checkoutBtn().height() + 10) >= (menuBox().offset().top + menuBox().height())) && wheelDelta < 0
}

function checkScrollPosition($event) {
    var wheelDelta = ($event.wheelDelta || ($event.detail*-1));
    if (needsPositioned(wheelDelta)) {
        db_adjustPosition($event);
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.returnValue = false;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function adjustHeight($event) {
    if ($event && ($event.type === 'mousewheel' || $event.type === 'DOMMouseScroll' || $event.type === 'resize')) {
        if (!checkScrollPosition($event)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/martyphee/pu1qncaL/3/

Update:
I seem to have found the issue.  It's with OSX inertia setting.  Once I turn that off the bounce goes away.  Any idea how to combat that?

Answer (score 0):

You could make the body 100% in height and disable scrolling. Afterwards you could create a div within the body which allows scrolling. This will disable the momentum scroll / bounce effect.

On document scroll do:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

https://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

maybe no JS is needed, try this css code on the body tag:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: none;
```